# javascript (iQuery ) first letter is exclamation

Tags: javascript, regex, letter

I want to check is the first letter of variable a (! - Exclamation )
Have any here an example for me ? i found other things but not for first letter is exclamation.
thanks so much for reply me

Comment: Are you trying to write regex that checks if the first character of a string is `!` or not?

Comment: What have you tried? This is not how SO works. You show your attempt and people provide fixes.

Comment: i know how to check the FIRST CHAR IN STRING but my question is - how can i check the (!) exclamation char ... i find only things for A-Z or number but not ONLY for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//using regex
let a = "!variable";

let test = /!/.test(a);

if (test) console.log("there is \"!\" somewhere in \"a\" variable");

//or not using regex

let char = a.split("", 1)[0];

if (char == "!") console.log("first letter is \"!\"");
```

The second part takes first letter and logs message if it is "!" , first part tests whole string in order to find "!". I'm not sure if there is a way to check that first letter is "!" using regex.

Comment: Thanks so much mate, that is exactly that what i needed